# Tiles 3.0 & Spring MVC settings

Tags: spring-mvc, configuration, tiles, spring-3

Is it possible to run Tiles 3.0 with Spring 3.0?

What is the needed configuration?

Comment: if someone has experience with it, please post a reference to a how to guide..

Comment: For anyone wondering, I have written a short blog post on Spring 3.2.2 with Tiles 3. Integration is surprisingly simple since the guys at Spring added support for Tiles 3. http://dhruvgairola.blogspot.ca/2013/03/spring-mvc-with-apache-tiles-3.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The current version of Spring only officially supports Tiles 2.

In order to get Tiles 3 working, you'd need to implement your own View Class, Tiles Configurer (if that is needed), etc.  This is something the Spring community would appreciate very much, but no easy feat I'm sure.

Hope this helps.

Comment: BTW, Spring since 3.2.RC2 should already have Tiles3 support. See https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-8825