# How to integrate Spring-security, struts2 and tiles3

Tags: struts2, spring-security, tiles

I am trying to integrate Springsecurity, struts2 and tiles3, once I run my application, it runs into following error, please let me know if I should include any other part of my code.

```
Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.tilesConfigurer] for bean with name 'tilesConfigurer' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.tilesConfigurer. Please see server.log for more details.
The module has not been deployed.
See the server log for details.
    at org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.deployment.devmodules.api.Deployment.deploy(Deployment.java:210)
    at org.netbeans.modules.maven.j2ee.ExecutionChecker.performDeploy(ExecutionChecker.java:178)
    at 
    org.netbeans.modules.maven.j2ee.ExecutionChecker.executionResult(ExecutionChecker.java:130)
    at 
    org.netbeans.modules.maven.execute.MavenCommandLineExecutor.run(MavenCommandLineExecutor.java:212)
    at org.netbeans.core.execution.RunClassThread.run(RunClassThread.java:153)
```

According to this question Spring does not support Tiles3 is that correct ? [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11739777/tiles-3-0-spring-mvc-settings)

**applicationContext.xml**

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?> 
    <beans xmlns='http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans' 
                    xmlns:context='http://www.springframework.org/schema/context' 
                    xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' 
                    xsi:schemaLocation='http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context    
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd'>

        <context:component-scan base-package='com.MyProject'/> 
        <bean id='internalResourceResolver' 
                     class='org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver'> 
            <property name='prefix' value='/Web Pages/'/> 
            <property name='suffix' value='.jsp'/> 
        </bean> 
        <bean 
         class='org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping'/>
        <bean 
         class='org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter'/> 
        <bean id='placeholderConfig' 

          class='org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer'/> 

        <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass">
            <value>
                org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.tileviewresolver
           </value>
        </property>
    </bean>
       <bean id="tilesConfigurer"
           class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.tilesConfigurer">
        <property name="definitions">
            <list>
                <value>/WEB-INF/tiles.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
    </beans>
```

**web.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"      
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-
    app_3_0.xsd">
        <context-param>
            <param-name>org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.DEFINITIONS_CONFIG</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/tiles.xml</param-value>
        </context-param>
        <listener>
       <listener-class>org.apache.tiles.extras.complete.CompleteAutoloadTilesListener</listener-   
       class>
        </listener>
           <listener>
            <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-
               class>  
        </listener>
         <context-param> 
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name> 
            <param-value>
                /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml
                /WEB-INF/myProject-security.xml 
                /WEB-INF/login-service.xml
            </param-value> 
        </context-param> 
        <filter> 
            <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name> 
            <filter-class> 
                org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy 
            </filter-class> 
        </filter> 

        <filter-mapping> 
            <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name> 
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern> 
        </filter-mapping>
        <filter>
            <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
            <filter-    
         class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-
            class>
        </filter>
        <filter-mapping>
            <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        </filter-mapping>
        <session-config>
            <session-timeout>
                30
            </session-timeout>
        </session-config>
        <welcome-file-list>
            <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        </welcome-file-list>
    </web-app>
```

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-
  instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-
         4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.myproject</groupId>
    <artifactId>MyProject</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>MyProject</name>

    <properties>
        <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <glassfish.embedded-static-shell.jar>C:\Program 
        Files\Java\jre7\bin\glassfish\lib\embedded\glassfish-embedded-static-
        shell.jar</glassfish.embedded-static-shell.jar>
        <netbeans.hint.deploy.server>gfv3ee6</netbeans.hint.deploy.server>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts2-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.8</version>
        </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-2.1-glassfish</artifactId>
            <version>9.1.02.B04.p0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts2-convention-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.14</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts2-dojo-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.14</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts-taglib</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>jdbc-stdext</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.sql</groupId>
            <artifactId>jdbc-stdext</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>glassfish-embedded-static-shell</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${glassfish.embedded-static-shell.jar}</systemPath>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.kenai.nbpwr</groupId>
            <artifactId>org-apache-commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2-201002241055</version>
            <type>nbm</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.24</version>
        </dependency>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbutils</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbutils</artifactId>
            <version>1.5</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.taglibs</groupId>
            <artifactId>taglibs-parent</artifactId>
            <version>3</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.zxing</groupId>
            <artifactId>javase</artifactId>
            <version>1.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.zxing</groupId>
            <artifactId>core</artifactId>
            <version>1.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxrpc</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
            <artifactId>fmt</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
            <type>tld</type>
        </dependency>
         <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
    <groupId>commons-digester</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-digester</artifactId>
    <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.opencsv</groupId>
            <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts2-tiles3-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.14</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>6.0</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>axis</groupId>
            <artifactId>axis</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-discovery</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-discovery</artifactId>
            <version>0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.6</version>
        </dependency>
     <dependency>
<groupId>log4j</groupId>
<artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
<version>1.2.15</version>
<exclusions>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
        <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
        <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
            <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
            <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
</exclusions>
</dependency>
            <dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.6</version>
</dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                    </compilerArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                            <silent>true</silent>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                    <version>6.0</version>
                                    <type>jar</type>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I understand...

I don't particularly understand spring security. Not considering it, this is the general flow:

request -> struts2 resolves and executes action -> render view (which will sometimes be a tiles result)

A tiles result should be thought of as a view. Tiles lets you factor the commonality out of the views but at the end of the day it is just a view.

When using spring security, is it typical to secure each and every jsp in a web application? 
If it isn't then I wouldn't try to secure the tiles views either.

Instead secure the struts2 actions... because if something is not secure the action will still execute and possibly bad things could happen. So block the "bad things" higher up the chain.

If this makes sense then you don't need any of that tiles based stuff in applicationContext.xml (just get rid of it). The error of course is happening because it can't resolve the class, but I have a feeling this class is really for spring-mvc integration, so just forget about it.

If you followed the tiles3-plugin integration guide then your web.xml contains:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.apache.tiles.extras.complete.CompleteAutoloadTilesListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

This will load everything needed for the struts2-tiles3 result to render.

Comment: good it works now should I open a new question for the menu stuff?

Comment: Sorry, yes. Comment too short... disco.

Comment: All right the new question is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16454135/how-to-provide-different-menu-according-to-rule-of-user