# How to show different menu according to rule of user using Tile3

Tags: struts2, spring-security, tiles

I am using tile3, spring security and struts2. I have different number of users, each with specific role, and each role should has access to a specific menu, I have the follwoing tile.xml file but I am not sure how to change it in a way to solve the issue.

Please let me know if you need me to provide any other part of my code.

```
<tiles-definitions>
    <definition name="baseLayout" template="/baseLayout.jsp">
        <put-attribute name="title"  value=""/>
        <put-attribute name="header" value="/header.jsp"/>
        <put-attribute name="menu" value=""/>
        <put-attribute name="body"   value=""/>
        <put-attribute name="footer"   value="/footer.jsp"/>
        <put-attribute name="register"  value="/register.jsp"/>
    </definition>

    <definition name="register1" extends="baseLayout">
        <put-attribute name="menu"   value="/menuAdmin.jsp"/>  
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/body.jsp"/>
    </definition>
    <definition name="register2" extends="baseLayout">
        <put-attribute name="menu"   value="/menuUser.jsp"/>  
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/body.jsp"/>    
     </definition>
       .....
```

As my application has many different pages, I have to create a separate definition for each request for each user's role. For example, there should only be a definition called register and the menu attribute should dynamically change based on role of requester, or any other way to make it simpler.

I am using the following to define the accessible sections for each role

```
<http auto-config="true" access-denied-page="/notFound.jsp" use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/Profile/view*" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" /> 
    <intercept-url pattern="/Search/view*" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" /> 
    <form-login login-page="/index" 
                authentication-failure-url="/index?error=1"
                default-target-url="/default"/> 
     <logout logout-success-url="/index.jsp"/>
</http>
```

I can use the following code to find the logged in user's role

```
 @Action
 public class Default {
    public String execute(){
        String role =    
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getAuthorities().toString();
        System.out.println("User's role:"+role);
        if(role.equalsIgnoreCase("[ROLE_ADMIN]"))
            return "Admin";
        return "";


    }

}
```

Comment: How is the role accessible? Is it accessible from a session object? Further consider with role based security usually users are assigned multiple roles. To keep the issue simple I'll assume the user is assigned a single role.

Comment: I need the code you would put in a struts2 action that would display the role for a specific user. With that we can do something interesting.

Comment: To be clear: String role = magic_code_to_get_role_as_string(); would suffice

Comment: @Quaternion question is updated now

Comment: Well I'll get you to do the work for me, because I'm going to configure spring security. 1) Enable static method access. 2) Rewrite the "SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getAuthorities().toString();" as an OGNL expression and display the role for the particular using the s:property tag.

Comment: This expression will be: `@fullyQualifedPackageName.SecurityContextHolder@context.authentication.authorities` what I don't know is what the full package.

Comment: what do you mean by enable static method access?

Comment: Just add `<constant name="struts.ognl.allowStaticMethodAccess" value="true"/>` right after the `<struts>` tag in struts.xml there are possible security ramifications but worry about those later.

Comment: If you don't do this we can't use OGNL to access static methods...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29634/discussion-between-jack-ramzi-and-quaternion)

Comment: @Quaternion, I have added new dependencies to it but still does not work :(

Comment: Remove the Spring security, test to see if tiles works correctly... if the struts2-tiles integration is fine... then you'll probably need help from Antonio (tiles mailing list). Tiles has the ability to test for roles directly within the configuration. This is using JEE role based security, a good question for him and one that I'd been meaning to ask is if you can override their means of looking up the role from a custom provider (such as Spring security)

Comment: @Quaternion, I have removed the configuration of Spring security from web.xml and changed the tile to <put-attribute name="menu" expression="OGNL: 'menu' + 'admin.jsp'"/> but it still shows the menuadmin.jsp rather than loading the file.

Comment: Do you need the path appended?

Comment: @Quaternion I enter fdgdfgdfg but it just shows that. Seems it does not consider it as a expression but a string.

Comment: Working on my own challenges... however update your question with your new tiles expressions. Hopefully will get a chance to look.

Comment: I am going to open a new question write the following for me to accept you as the correct answer then I will create a new question <put-attribute name="menu" expression="OGNL: 'menu' + 'admin.jsp'"/>

Comment: @Quaternion, the new question is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16515571/tile-does-not-work-properly-with-ognl-expressions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following

```
 <put-attribute name="header" expression="OGNL:@com.project.Default@getRole() + '.jsp'"/>
```